# Derivation: Discerning difference between arithmetic expression with parenthesis versus without using abstract syntax trees

Tags: derivatives, first-order-logic, regular-expressions

I am trying to illustrate the expression: **( 3 * 4 + 5 * 6 + 7 )** using an abstract syntax tree. I have already illustrated the expression: **( 3 * (4 + 5) * (6 + 7) )**.

[image: exp1]

Could someone please illustrate the expression without parenthesis with order of left-most first. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here is an updated image of what I think may be correct, but please correct me if it is not. Thanks.

[image: xxx]

Comment: The tree is not unique. Here is one: $(+\  (+\  (*\  3\  4)\  (* \ 5 \ 6)) \ 7)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Your answer to my question looks correct, however I don't understand your critique to my current tree illustration. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: No critique, just pointing out that neither tree is unique. The addition (or multiplication) is binary and can be grouped in two ways, the usual convention is left associative.

Comment: @copper.hat I have added a new image of my progress, could you please take a look and tell me if it is correct?

Comment: That is not what I was thinking. I was thinking of something like $(+\   (*\  3\  4)\  (+\ \ (* \ 5 \ 6) \ 7))$ as an alternative to that in my first comment.

Comment: @copper.hat could you please elaborate what you mean by "not unique"?

Comment: You can write $a+b+c$ as $a+(b+c)$ or $(a+b)+c$, for example (unless you have some presumed associativity).

Comment: @copper.hat I updated my question to indicate that I am aiming for left-most presumed association.

Comment: Then there is no ambiguity.